# Legal defense against paying taxes for supporting terrorist?

Tags: united-states, tax-law

The United States has undoubtedly supported many questionable groups over the years including groups now designated as terrorist organizations. If someone decided they did not want their tax dollars to fund terrorist, nazis, mercenary groups, etc., would this be a viable defense in court regarding the non-payment of taxes?

Comment: Im reminded of the saying one mans terrorist is anothers freedom fighter.

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/26078/could-i-object-to-paying-us-federal-taxes-on-moral-grounds/26081

Comment: If you could, don't you think everybody would be doing it?

Comment: As far as I know, literally *every* argument proposing a justification for not paying taxes has been shot down in court, if it even makes it that far.  The next time you have such an idea, you will probably want to phrase your question not as "Would this be a viable defense?" but rather as "When was the last time someone tried this, and how large a fine (or how much prison time) did they get?"

Comment: The IRS has an [article on "frivolous tax positions"](https://www.irs.gov/privacy-disclosure/the-truth-about-frivolous-tax-arguments-introduction) which covers many things similar to this, so it'd be good reading if you are thinking along these lines.  Odds are it's been seen and rejected.

Comment: In fact yours is #1 in Section D.

Comment: @NateEldredge All these comments could probably be stitched together to make a high-quality answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first point that is already well-established in law is that there really is a legal requirement to pay taxes, not just federal income taxes, but taxes in general. On rare occasion, there is a legal dispute as to whether something is a tax (Obamacare) or whether a particular authority is allowed to levy such a tax. Let us assume that the tax in question is legally levied.

Some taxes are independent of any specific intended purpose (e.g. federal income tax, state sales tax). Some are for a specific purpose (Medicare tax, the taxes that are local school levies). Even when a taxing authority corruptly but legally misdirects the funds designated for a specific purpose, you are still required to pay the tax. It's not that a tax law could not be written which allows a person to refuse to pay a tax if they judge that the revenues are being misdirected, it's that the law-makers did no cripple the tax law with such a provision.

As far as I know, no taxing authority anywhere allows a person to refuse to pay a tax is they disagree with the use of the taxes, which is to say, taxation is mandatory, not voluntary. If it is voluntary, it is known as a "contribution". You are allowed to contribute to some governmental purpose, you are *required* to pay taxes. You can't overcome the requirement to pay taxes on First Amendment grounds (being forced to support something that you don't like). The IRS has a FAQ that addresses [the First Amendment argument](https://www.irs.gov/privacy-disclosure/the-truth-about-frivolous-tax-arguments-section-i-d-to-e#contentiond1), with a mass of supporting court cases (US v. Lee, 455 U.S. 252; Jenkins v. Commissioner, 483 F.3d 90; US v. Indianapolis Baptist Temple, 224 F.3d 627; Adams v. Commissioner, 170 F.3d 173; US v. Ramsey, 992 F.2d 831; and so on).

Comment: tl;dr " If someone decided they did not want their tax dollars to fund terrorist, nazis, mercenary groups, etc., would this be a viable defense in court regarding the non-payment of taxes?" No.